# How to install Snowleopard on VirtualBox?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox

I would like to try snowleopard on VirtualBox on my Thinkpad T510.

I am using Win7 64bit + VirtualBox 3.2. I created a Mac OSX server virtual machine in my virtualbox and start the VM using empireEFIv1085.iso.

This boot process is fine, and it tells me to change image and hit F5. I tried every snowleopard image I have, every image gives me a black screen. There's not even one response, just a blackscreen, but it looks running rather than hanging.

What should I do with that?

The following is the setting of the virtual machine in VirtualBox:

```
Base Memory:             2048 MB
Processor(s):            1
VT-x/AMD-V:              Enabled
Nested Paging:           Enabled
Video Memory:            128 MB
3D Acceleration:         Enabled
2D Video Acceleration:   Disabled
Remote Display Server:   Disabled
```

and my Thinkpad T510 has i5 CPU, 8G Memory, and NVIDIA NVS 3100M.

Thanks a lot for your attention. It's driving me crazy!

Best Regards.
Larry.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox does not support the client version of OSX. Only the Server is supported.

Comment: Server is only supported when running on Apple (server) hardware.  Unless a EULA has been updated that i missed...